# How do I make shapes abut top to bottom in Powerpoint 365?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office365

How can I vertically align two objects in Powerpoint 365 (Windows) so the bottom of one exactly overlaps with the top of the other? I don't see a snap to object option:

[image: two wide rectangles labeled "top" and "bottom" aligned horizontally with a small vertical gap]

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to turn Snap Objects To Grid *off*, unless you're also snapping the shapes you've drawn to the grid. In the same dialog box, turn Display Smart Guides *on*. That will give you little red hairline indicators when the shapes line up.